# Get effective road from a point to a point (BFS on matrix)

Tags: java, matrix, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

I have a matrix with 0 and X (0 means you can walk through and X means wall).
I have a start point and an end point.
I used BFS to find the shortest path (length) between start and end. (it works)
But now I need to find the effective road and I don't know how to do it. (I thought I can use an Lee algorithm recursiv).

```
Example:

5 5 
SXXXF 
0XX00 
0XX0X 
0000X 
XXXXX
```

Length is 8 and the road is: (1, 1) -> (2, 1) -> (3, 1) ->(4, 2) -> (4, 3) -> (3, 4) -> (2, 4) -> (1, 5).
I have 8 directions.

So, I used BFS to get the length (8) but I don't know how to get the road.
Some ideas or pseudocodes?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's pretty simple:
  Store the "predecessor" of each node. Be it in another matrix, embedded into the original map, or as `Map`. Even a tree-structure would work, if it's bidirectional.

Without code, I can't got about showing you a possible solution, but in the end, all you need is a mapping `node -> node from which it was visited`. E.g. in your example you move from `(1, 1)` to `(2, 1)`, so the mapping would be `(2, 1)->(1, 1)`. This can easily be implemented within the BFS-routine.

Finish running the algorithm, while filling your mapping. Afterwards you start of by searching the predecessor of the finish node, then the predecessor of the predecessor of the finish node, and so on until you're back at the start point.

Comment: Woa..great idea. It works for small matrix..I'll try now on someyhing huge :d Thanks!